# xml file to generate answer_url for plivo application

Tags: java, xml, phone-call, plivo

I am in process of integrating  a plivo application in java application .Here i am struck in url parameter.here i have to create a xml file and pass it to answer_url key parameter as a value.

As a reference to this https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/application/#create-an-application and  https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/application/#answer-url here they have not mentioned exactly what we have to do.

Here how should i create xml file so that i could pass url to answer_url parameter.Please help me on this i am very new to plivo.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To create an Plivo application you don't need to make an XML file. Rather you need to make a Plivo Application API request or use the java helper library. Here is sample code to make a Plivo Application:

```
package plivoexample;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import com.plivo.helper.api.client.*;
import com.plivo.helper.api.response.application.Application;
import com.plivo.helper.exception.PlivoException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        String auth_id = "Your_AUTH_ID";
        String auth_token = "Your_AUTH_TOKEN";
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI(auth_id, auth_token, "v1");

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        // The URL Plivo will fetch when a call executes this application
        parameters.put("answer_url","http://example.com");
        parameters.put("app_name","Testing_App"); // The name of your application

        try {
            // Create an Application
            Application resp = api.createApplication(params);
            System.out.println((resp));
        } catch (PlivoException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

See https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/application-api/ for more details.